# How do I get selected value of jquery spinner?

Tags: jquery

I have 7 spinners on a page and I need to figure out how to get the value of the spinner and put it in a asp label. I can figure out how to pass the value to a label but I'm stuck on getting the value of the spinner so I can pass it along to a label..
here is my fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/Cwm76/cV85E/

here is the code for the spinner

```
function updateTopBottom() {
    var $el = $('#topbottom'),
        m;
}


$(function () {


    $('#normal input').spinner();


    $('#topbottom input').spinner({
        min: 0,
        max: 12,
        step: 0.5,
        stop: updateTopBottom
    })
            .parent()
            .find('.ui-spinner-up').addClass('ui-corner-tl').end()
            .find('.ui-spinner-down').addClass('ui-corner-bl');

    updateTopBottom();
});
```

Thanks to all for any input.

Comment: http://api.jqueryui.com/spinner/#method-value

Comment: Thank you Edward, I'm going to set it up with a label at each spinner. The other programmer I sent the code to will find it easier if I use separate invisible labels

Comment: @cadrell0, thanks the page is now book marked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `spinner` is being applied to an `input` tag as you see here:

```
$('#topbottom input').spinner({
```

Therefore you would get the value from `input`.

```
// This is the callback function you specified
// So we would retrieve the value here
function updateTopBottom() {
        var $el = $('#topbottom'),
            m;
     console.log($('#topbottom input').val());
}
```

Comment: oh wow, I didn't even think of that! Thanks, I should have been paying more attention when I did this

Comment: @user2970223 It's okay, we all gloss over things sometimes.

Comment: I tried what you suggested, and your answer is correct, i'm just running into an issue putting the value to an asp label

Answer (score 0):

You can get an array of your 7 spinners by `$(".ui-spinner-input")` and then get each value by `.val()` in `$.each()` loop.

```
$.each($(".ui-spinner-input"), function(index,value){    
    console.log($(value).val());
});
```

Comment: I understand what you are saying but the other developer might not know how to deal with arrays, he's only been programming periodically for 2 years

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this fork. http://jsfiddle.net/5MvTn/

```
$('#topbottom input').focusout(function() { alert (this.value); });
```

The spinner just set the numbers in the value attribute of the input tag.

Comment: Thanks, there are so many answers for this and I appreciate everyone's help